# Returning from inner nested coroutine by label Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, coroutinescope

Use case: I have a lot of operations that I want to happen asynchronously from the main thread but also in parallel with each other.

```
val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
val items = // List of items to do something.

scope.launch {
    items.forEach { item ->
        scope.launch {
            if (itemFailsValidation(item)) {
                // Here I want to skip this item but continue the forEach loop.
                return@launch // "There is more than one label with such a name in this" scope"
            }
            doSomethingThatMightTakeABit(item)
         }
     }
}
```

If I try to add a label, like `inner@scope.launch`, editor says "Label is redundant, because it can not be referenced in either ''break'', ''continue'', or ''return'' expression"

Does anyone know a good way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we need to return from a lambda expression, we have to [label it and qualify the **return**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels). For your case to return from inner coroutine:

```
scope.launch {
    items.forEach { item ->
        scope.launch innerScope@ {
            if (itemFailsValidation(item)) {
                return@innerScope
            }
            doSomethingThatMightTakeABit(item)
        }
    }
}
```

But we can simplify your case and rewrite code without using a label:

```
scope.launch {
    items.forEach { item ->
        if (!itemFailsValidation(item)) {
            scope.launch { doSomethingThatMightTakeABit(item) }
        }
    }
}

// OR

items.forEach { item ->
    if (!itemFailsValidation(item)) {
        scope.launch { doSomethingThatMightTakeABit(item) }
    }
}
```

If you want to wait for all coroutines to finish and do something on UI thread:

```
scope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    processItemsInBackground()

    // update UI after processing is finished
}

suspend fun processItemsInBackground() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    // withContext waits for all children coroutines
    items.forEach { item ->
        if (!itemFailsValidation(item)) {
            launch { doSomethingThatMightTakeABit(item) }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code simplification idea, yeah I could just flip the null check and then i dont need the launch, good inight!

Answer (score 2):

You can change the name of the lambda using `name@` keyword.

Example:

```kotlin
scope.launch outerCoroutine@ {
    items.forEach { item ->
        scope.launch {
            if (itemFailsValidation(item)) {
                return@outerCoroutine
            }
            doSomethingThatMightTakeABit(item)
         }
     }
}
```

This feature isn't properly documented, but some docs like [This expressions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html) have demonstration usages in it, and some functions defined in standard library uses it.

**Edit:** This is actually documented at [Return and Jumps](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helps, thanks for the doc link as well.